# Composing functions that yield in ruby

Tags: ruby

New to ruby language. I'm aware that ruby has `then` keyword to compose blocks and `<<` for `proc` objects to compose proc. However, the question I have focuses on named functions that `yield` value to each other. I'm wondering what is the best way to implement such pipeline paradigm in ruby.

Consider the following code I came up with. I don't know if this is idiomatic.

```
# @param [Proc] lproc
# @param [Proc] rproc
def then_proc(lproc, rproc)
  proc { |x| lproc.call(x, &rproc) }
end

def n(x)
  yield x
end

def branch(x)
  yield x + 1 if x > 2
  0
end

def add_one(x)
  x + 1
end

then_proc(method(:n).to_proc, 
  then_proc(method(:branch).to_proc, method(:add_one).to_proc)).call 2
 => 0

then_proc(method(:n).to_proc, 
  then_proc(method(:branch).to_proc, method(:add_one).to_proc)).call 3
 => 4
```

To me this is more similar to the forms of pipelines seen in other programming languages (`Promise` in javascript, for example), because functions can have branches to not yield and terminate early, whereas `then` requires the pipeline to be completely executed. I'm wondering if there is some mechanism in ruby that can achieve this. If not, how would go about this problem?

Thank you.

### Clarification on the question

I would like to build a pipeline using a series of **named** functions that *might* but *not necessarily* yield to a block. Per my understanding, in the existing `ruby` `then/yield_self` function, the block is *always* invoked, which is not the intention. Notice in the toy example I gave, the final `add_one` block is only executed if previous branch function receives `x > 2`.

Comment: You might like https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-transformer - "a library that allows you to compose procs into a functional pipeline using left-to-right function composition."

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`Enumerator::Lazy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerator/Lazy.html) – it _"allows constructing chains of operations without evaluating them immediately, and evaluating values on as-needed basis."_

Comment: Take a look at `yield_self` https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Object/yield_self

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve here. This seems far from idiomatic as it's rare you'd ever need `method(:x).to_proc` in actual code. Normally there's far better ways of solving the problem.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do, in words?

Comment: The algorithm description, input, and expected output might be helpful to answer the question.

Comment: I believe `yield_self` is just an alias of `then`. @Yakov

Comment: @D.SM I've updated the question.

Comment: @tadman I'm aware. That's exactly why I don't think this approach is very idiomatic.

Comment: If you could better clarify your goals it'd be a lot easier to come up with an idiomatic solution. A more concrete example would help considerably. Talking about "might yield" doesn't really make sense on its own.

Comment: @tadman Okay let me put in another way. Say I want to apply a series of modifications to an object. At some intermediate step, the object might be type x or type y, and I need to perform some additional modifications to the object if it belongs to type x. The way I'm constructing the pipeline is that I yield current value to a block (next function) if it needs further modifications.

Comment: @tadman I think another way to approach this problem would be to just supply a method object as argument, as opposed a block, so I don't have to call `to_proc`.

Comment: This is still kind of hazy, like a very specific example would help considerably. This could be interpreted any number of ways. This could be done with inheritance, depending on your circumstances. Are you talking about a series of *Decorator* passes?

Comment: @tadman I'm sorry that this is as much specific as I can get. I would says it's more like visitor patterns. Let me think about how to formulate the situation and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to build a pipeline using a series of named functions that might but not necessarily yield to a block.

A method does not need to yield.

The following implements a conditional using procs:

```
def _if(v, cond, yes, no = nil)
  if cond.call(v)
    yes.call(v)
  else
    no&.call(v)
  end
end

cond = lambda { |v| v > 2 }
yes = lambda { |v| v + 1 }
no = lambda { |v| 0 }

_if(1, cond, yes, no)
_if(3, cond, yes, no)
_if(1, cond, yes)
```